# Reinstall ubuntu from scratch while keeping mdadm raid

Tags: mdadm

So I have been stuck on 11.10 for fear of doing a dist upgrade and breaking everything trying to go up multiple versions. It has come a time that I finally should move up to at least 14.04 and looking for some advice.

Currently I have the OS and main partitions installed on a separate 500GB hard drive and a raid 5 mdadm array over 5 other disks. I am worried that I'll screw something up after I get 14.04 installed and not be able to re build my raid array.

Looking on advice on best steps or practice to ensure I have a smooth(er) upgrade experience without losing everything.

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

1. Do a full system backup before you start.  (Read [the following article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) if you don't know how. You're user type 4)
2. Download the CD and do an upgrade using the CD instead of the Internet (Murpy's law etc)

What do you mean that your RAID5 *is* your back-up?  A RAID5 is *just a protection against single drive failure!* **It is NOT a back-up!**  Borrow, bribe, buy anything but *make a back-up!*

No! Really!  ;-)